# jsp form with two actions and one submit button

Tags: jsp, servlets, request

I am using an MVC jsp model to impelement a small application, in one of the jsp pages I have a form that calls the servlet:
register.jsp

```
<form name="info" method="post" action="../MyServlet">
<!--some fields here-->
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

within the MyServlet:

```
if(user.isvalid())
   response.sendRedirect("jsp/Confirm");
//some else lines here
```

I am trying to have register.jsp to call the MyServlet and Confirm.jsp, so I can use request.getParameter("element") within Confirm.jsp to get parameters entered in the info form and display it on Confirm.jsp.

Comment: let me understand. you have a login page called register.jsp. In this page the user will provide some user and some password and these are being sent to MyServlet. Inside MyServlet, it gets the user and the password and check if they're valid. If they are, you want to open the Confirm.jsp page, passing the user information as a parameter, so you can show a message like "user xyz, are you sure?". Something like this?

Comment: if it is, you have two good options here. You can add this data to a session object or you can forward as request attributes.

Comment: I have used to session object when the user is loggedin, but this is not for the login, this is when a user is already loggedin as admin and want to create a new user.                                   String username=(String)session.getAttribute("UserName"); within Confirm.jsp will give the admin username not the one that you passed in the info form.

Comment: Oh, I finally figured out what you are asking.  This requires that you FORWARD the request rather than REDIRECT.